# css3 div throwing box shadow onto textarea

Tags: html, textarea, z-index, css

```
 <div id="top-toolbar-with-box-shadow"></div>
 <textarea id="editor" class="textarea-with-zindex-below-toolbar" ></textarea>
```

Applying z-index -1 to the textarea brings it below the toolbar.
The toolbar itself has a -moz-box-shadow property to cast shadows on underlying elements.
The textarea does not catch the shadow.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Duh me.... I just made the textarea background:transparent

Maybe this might help some other